# Identify some commit variable that trigger my yaml in azure devops Build and push an image to container registry

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-container-registry

I hope someone can help me.

I have a yalm file in azure devops that fires every time I commit to a branch of a repo that is inside Repos in azure devops, basically Build and push an image to container registry.

The problem I have is that when I search Azure Container registry the way I have to identify the built docker is from the last tag that was made e.g.(22,23,24), and I need to identify it with a string that I want to put dynamically on it from commit information that fired this pipeline.

I would like the built docker tag to be called as a name of the any commit variable that triggers, the commit variable example: "MLM3232" in the Azure Container registry tag to be named "MLM3232" in the same way.

the yaml I have is:

```
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- main

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'privateprivateprivate'
  imageRepository: 'privateprivateprivate'
  containerRegistry: 'privateprivateprivate'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  
  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

Comment: The commit message is a bad candidate to be used as a tag, since commit messages are human-readable strings of text that may contain linebreaks, special characters, and all sorts of things that aren't valid in image tags. I'd recommend using the commit hash and something like GitVersion to generate a standard incrementing semver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem I had.

changed in yaml.

tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

per

tag: '$(Build.SourceVersion)'

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#identity_values

Build.SourceVersion:
The latest version control change of the triggering repo that is included in this build.

Git: The commit ID.

TFVC: the changeset.

This variable is agent-scoped, and can be used as an environment variable in a script and as a parameter in a build task, but not as part of the build number or as a version control tag.

This way I do have a way to identify commit information in container registry tags.

However, I don't understand why they don't recommend it for version control tag. For now it's good for me!